# Does the solution to the following differential equation exists?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a physics student and I encounter a the following differential equation for the function $\phi(r)$ (scalar field on Kerr metric)

$$\frac{-2\phi-2(M-r)\phi'+(P^2-2Mr+r^2)\phi''}{r^2}=-m^2\phi$$

The parameters are $M,P,m$, physically they represent some properties of the black hole and the field $\phi$. The only thing that is relevant is  that $M>P$ for the case under consideration.

We further define the following
$$r_{\pm}=M\pm\sqrt{M^2-P^2}$$

With this, the boundary conditions we hope to introduce is that $\phi(r)$ vanish at $+\infty$ and $\phi(r_{+})$ is regular.

Is there a general solution of $\phi(r)$ or even an approximate solution for $\phi(r)$ for large r? I know the general solution exists for $m=0$, but it seems that Mathematica can not solve it for $m>0$.

Edit: I only need solution for $r>r_{+}$

Comment: For large $r$ one can neglect $2 \ll m^2 r^2$, then $r^2 \phi''+2r\phi'+m^2r^2\phi=0$, then $\phi(r)=\frac{a\cos(mr+b)}{r}$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants.